# How to change the text color of month in GitHub square calendar android

Tags: android

I am using this GitHub [calendar](https://github.com/square/android-times-square) in my app. Now see this picture below -

[image]

The title of the month is dark and it does not suit the theme. So how can I change it?

```
 <color name="Navigation_Color">@color/motivationQuoteColor</color> <!--same as selected color-->

    <color name="calendar_selected_day_bg">#c2e4ff</color> 
    <color name="calendar_highlighted_day_bg">@color/toolbarColor</color>  
    <color name="calendar_text_selected">@color/colorPrimaryDark</color>
    <color name="calendar_text_unselectable">@color/whiteTextColor</color>
    <color name="calendar_text_active">@color/whiteTextColor</color>
    <color name="calendar_text_inactive">@color/motivationQuoteColor</color>
    <color name="calendar_divider">@color/whiteTextColor</color>
    <color name="calendar_bg">@color/motivationQuoteColor</color>
    <color name="calendar_inactive_month_bg">@color/motivationQuoteColor</color>
    <color name="calendar_active_month_bg">@color/motivationQuoteColor</color> 
    <color name="calendar_selected_range_bg">@color/motivationQuoteColor</color>
```

Above are the only choices of colors, provided by the project from GitHub. I want to make the color white for the month's title. By the way, I searched google and I found [that](https://github.com/square/android-times-square/issues/487) (github.com) but it did not work for me.

Edit - I found [that](https://github.com/square/android-times-square/issues/380) (GitHub issue) one also but not worked

Here is my XML code:

```
 <com.squareup.timessquare.CalendarPickerView
                android:id="@+id/calendar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="370dp"
                android:background="@color/calendar_bg">

            </com.squareup.timessquare.CalendarPickerView>
```

Comment: can you just post up your xml where you declared this CalendarPickerView

Comment: yeah sure, I edited the question

Comment: try the following solution @Vijay

Comment: I did not understand please add some comments in the answer

Comment: see following...i dont think it needed more info ...please let me know if doesnt worked

Comment: does the solution worked ?have you tried?

Comment: yes i am trying but it is not working, give me two more minutes

Comment: `it is not working` what you are getting?provide some details ..what happens after you added my solution?

Comment: things have changed, but the color of the month not changing, all the dates color have changed to white and the month title is on left side

Comment: see I just want to change the month title color to white that's all and thanks for supporting, I need help

Comment: i have edited my answer....add following once again...i added textcolor and chnged gravity have a look

Comment: <item name="android:color">@color/whiteTextColor</item> [last second line in style tag]. I have changed the color here to white am I doing right

Comment: yes but did you add this --> `<item name="android:textColor">@color/colorAccent</item>` ?? also add `<item name="android:gravity">center</item>`

Comment: ok, it's working, thanks WINI for your support and your time. Sorry for taking that much time. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after going through the link of github you have given

add the following code in your styles.xml:-

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
.
.
.
<style name="CustomCalendarTitle">
<item name="android:textSize">@dimen/calendar_text_medium</item>
<item name="android:gravity">center</item>
<item name="android:paddingBottom">@dimen/calendar_month_title_bottommargin</item>
<item name="android:paddingTop">@dimen/calendar_month_topmargin</item>
<item name="android:color">@color/custom_calendar_text_selector</item>
 <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorAccent</item>

</style>
</resources>
```

Replace this:-

```
 <com.squareup.timessquare.CalendarPickerView
            android:id="@+id/calendar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="370dp"
            android:background="@color/calendar_bg">

        </com.squareup.timessquare.CalendarPickerView>
```

by

use this in xml:-

```
<com.squareup.timessquare.CalendarPickerView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/calendar_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/custom_background"
android:clipToPadding="false"
android:paddingBottom="16dp"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp"
android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
app:tsquare_dayBackground="@drawable/custom_calendar_bg_selector"
app:tsquare_dayTextColor="@color/custom_calendar_text_selector"
app:tsquare_displayDayNamesHeaderRow="false"
app:tsquare_dividerColor="@color/transparent"
app:tsquare_headerTextColor="@color/custom_header_text"
app:tsquare_titleTextStyle="@style/CustomCalendarTitle"
/>
```

Comment: last line of styles.xml code  <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorAccent</item> is the key to change the color